# Production server unable to add or modifiy products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have move my site to dev server to production server every thing working fine but unable to add products

I have get bellow error "Provisional headers are shown"  (See in firebug the script are running without response")

IN REQUEST HEADER

```
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhOwWpY5AtD644oAG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a cached resource and your browser does not have to contact the server, you won't get a 304 not modified or any HTTP status at all because a HTTP request won't be made

for reference please check this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger/21179105#21179105